# How can I re `./configure` on a package installed via `apt-get`?

Tags: apt, php

I have installed PHP using `apt-get`.

I need to enable PDO_OCI using:

`$ ./configure --with-pdo-oci=instantclient,/usr,10.2.0.3`

as per http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-oci.php.

How can I do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The packages you download via `apt` are pre-compiled binaries. You'll have to build PHP from source using those options.

You can get the source from the PHP website or using for example:

`apt-get source php5`

Comment: So there is no way to add options while installing via `apt-get`? In this case every time an update is released I would have to update manually?

Comment: @user4166144 correct - you would have to manually update every release if you have a custom binary with custom changes.

Answer (score 0):

You can't.

The `./configure` script creates Makefiles - recipes how to make the actual program.

When you invoke `make` you create the actual program using these recipes.

The actual program - the binary executable file will likely be different from the one installed by `apt-get`. Sometimes these differences are small but sometimes they may require extra dependencies and/or configuration files. If this is your case then manually replacing the program file will likely break your system.

Even if you replace the package supplied binary file (`/usr/bin/php5` or whatever) with your own and nothing breaks, next time there is an update of the php package your file will be overwritten by `apt-get` without warning, so don't do that.

What I would do in your situation is install the newly compiled php in directory /usr/local - *along* with the existing php. Then configure apache to use your php rather than the one supplied by the package manager.

Once you do that make sure you subscribe to the PHP security list and apply any security related patches as soon as possible. Failure to do so will leave your server exposed to hackers.